# mysql make a calculation based on several results

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table with fields ID, action and value. ID is the record name, action is the identifier of what does the value represent. The values of ID in the table are duplicated with different actions and values.

Example:

```
ID      action      value
3603    1           78
3603    2           2
3603    3           1
5645    1           45
etc...
```

Now I would like to construct a select statement that would somehow get values where ID=3603 and the formula is (if action 1 then value*10, if action 2 then value*5 and if action 3 then value*2). The result for 3603 is 792.

On top of that I need this to be joined to another table where I have the same ID value (unique) and I need to order by this sum both tables...

Is that possible or should I do some cumulative table that holds this sums for each record? Problem is this is statistics calculations so every ID will get 3 inputs of the actions for every month and every year (monthly statistics).

Comment: can you explain better the cumulative statistic case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id,action,sum(
CASE t.action 
  WHEN 1 then t.value * 10 
  when 2 then value*5 
  when 3 then value*2 end
) AS S

from table_multy t join table_single s on t.id=s.id
group by t.id
order by ( sum(
CASE t.action 
  WHEN 1 then t.value * 10 
  when 2 then value*5 
  when 3 then value*2 end
) + s.other_val )
```

to save in a historical table use:

```
insert into thistory (col1,clo2,clon) select ....
```

Comment: So it is best to use simple history table with the calculation already done I guess...

Answer (score 1):

```
 select sum(
 case 
 when action = 1 then value * 10
 when action = 2 then value * 5
 when action = 3 then value * 2
 end) as total
 from table
 where id = 3603
```

Comment: Thanx, but I still get multiple results not one. Should I sum the product?

Comment: Thanx. So I could join this table with my other table or better to do a temporary cumulatie table to do simple join with tables (I have to group this ID's together somehow)

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(CASE t.action WHEN  1 then t.value * 10 when 2 then value*5 when 3 then value*2 end) from table t
group by t.id
```

the above select will calculate sum for the given table on the basis of id's

Comment: Thanx. It is using temporay tables... I guess this will always be slow to calculate, perhaps I should put this sums to another table from time to time...

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible way, with multiple tables and an order by.  It should be fairly efficient with just 3 values per month.

```
select table_with_fields.ID, 
   table_2.field_1,
   table_2.field_2,
   sum(
      CASE action 
         when 1 then value * 10
         when 2 then value * 5
         when 3 then value * 2
       END) as full_amount
from table_with_fields 
   join table_2 on table_with_fields.id = table_2.id
group by table_with_fields.ID, 
   table_2.field_1,
   table_2.field_2
order by full_amount
```

Comment: Yes it is 3 values for ONE UNIQUE ID, I have 15.000 ID's ;-(